# Как парсить статистику отдельного поста в ВК?

Tags: python, парсер, vkontakte-api

Никак не могу найти, как парсить статистику конкретного поста в ВК. Написал парсер для статистики постов группы в целом, но как указывать url конкретного поста не нашел. В принимаемых данных также нет адреса поста, только id. Непонятно, как url поста соотносится с id. Кто знает, подскажите.

```
import requests
import csv

token = 'token'
version = 5.102
domain = 'my_comics'

response = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get',
                        params={
                            'access_token': token,
                            'v': version,
                            'domain': domain,
                        }
                        )
data = response.json()['response']['items']

def file_writer(data):
    with open('list.csv', 'w') as file:
        a_pen = csv.writer(file)
        a_pen.writerow(('likes', 'comments', 'reposts', 'views'))
        for post in data:
            a_pen.writerow((post['likes']['count'], post['comments']['count'], post['reposts']['count'], post['views']['count']))

file_writer(data)
```

Comment: https://vk.com/dev/stats.getPostReach ?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. но в документации к api написано: "Статистика записей в настоящий момент доступна только для сообществ с количеством участников от 5000 и выше, а также официальных сообществ". Проблема в том, что некоторые посты публикуются в сообществах, которые не соответствуют таким требованиям

Comment: Тогда, попробовать самим анализировать через обработку https://vk.com/dev/wall.get

Comment: К сожалению, своим умом пока не дойду. Спасибо за помощь